CriteriaBuilder Date with dash ("-") not working
I want to build a query like this:
fun expiryDate(searchString: String?): Specification<T> {
    return Specification<T> { root, _, cb ->
        cb.like(root.get<Date>("expiryDate").`as`(String::class.java), "%$searchString%")
    }
}

The Date is stored in Postgres like "yyyy-MM-dd". When I input "2024" as search sting I get results. I can also search for month and days. But when I use "2024-09-13" as search string the result is always emtpy. What am I missing here?

Are you definitely passing a hyphen-minus kind of dash ('\u002D') and not, for example, an en dash ('\u2013')?

Yes, is there a good way to debug this?
